# Issues with white space while converting string to long

Tags: java, string, for-loop, long-integer

I am trying to just separate 3 numbers from a string and print them to the string as longs. I need my program to use the white space as a separator to indicate that I'm at the end of this number. I then need to start the next number as a new iteration of the loop. However it crashes due to not understanding the white space cannot be converted I think.

What can I do about this?

```
String cipherTxt = "45963254 45231582 896433482 ";
for(int i=0; i<cipherTxt.length(); i++){
     String numberAsString = cipherTxt.substring(i,i+9);
     long number = Long.parseLong(numberAsString);
     System.out.println("The number is: " + number);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just split the string? `String[] numbers = text.split(" ");`

Comment: If spaces bother you, use the `trim()` method of  `String` .

Comment: I have to keep the spaces. I'm not familiar with split...what exactly is that doing?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try something like this:

```
String cipherTxt = "45963254 45231582 896433482 ";
String[] splitted = cipherTxt.split("\\s+");

for(String s : splitted){
     long number = Long.parseLong(s);
     System.out.println("The number is: " + number);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me your for loop as I would write it so standard? and can you also explain splitted? @dambros

Comment: You should `trim()` before splitting or something like a double space first will cause an invalid entry on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try with simpler `Scanner` class, as

```
String txt = "45963254 45231582 896433482 ";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(txt);
while(scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLong());
```

Or, maybe `String.split()` if you like

```
String txt = "45963254 45231582 896433482 ";
String[] tokens = txt.split(" ");
for(String temp:tokens)
    System.out.println(Long.parseLong(temp));
```

Comment: Can someone explain these for loops?? Im not understand the notation at all.

Comment: I can only point you [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) [and here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
String cipherTxt = "45963254 45231582 896433482 ";
String[] splitted = cipherTxt.split("\\s+");

for(String s : splitted){
     long number = Long.parseLong(s);
     System.out.println(number);
}
```

this for loop is iterating through every String in the array splitted
then it makes the text into long.
you could also write it like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < splitted.length;i++){
     long number = Long.parseLong(splitted[i]);
     System.out.println(number);
}
```

hope i helped!

Edit:
Ofcourse if you have any questions, ask!

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `\d+` to find a number. Loop through all given numbers and save them to the `List` so you can use stored variables again afterwards.

```
String txt = "45963254 45231582 896433482 ";

List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(txt);
while (m.find()) {
   long l = Long.parseLong(m.group());
   list.add(l);
   System.out.println(l);
}
```

In case you want the array as the output, add this under the cycle:

```
Long[] numbers = list.toArray(new Long[list.size()]);
```